# Hour calculation in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have project in which user gets specific number of hours for month respective to their subscription and if he had some hours remains at the end of month his remaining hours would be added in next month hours. For example if the user is subscribed to 1400 hours subscription and he has 20 hours left at the end of month so in the next month he get 1420 hours. However in my database hours are stored in this form 1400:00:00 so i get the value 20:00:00 how do i add 1400:00:00.

Comment: strtotime($hours) + (14400 * 60 * 60);

Comment: If your database corrupts your data and converts 1400 to 20, how can PHP fix it? Wouldn't it make more sense to fix it at database level?

Comment: how can i fix it at database level

Comment: Can you please elaborate how `strtotime($hours)` makes any kind of sense?

Comment: @hakre: `strtotime($hours, 0)` would make some sense.

Comment: @hakre if you have the solution for my problem then tell me. You have asked what i had tried i told you if i know what to try then i didnt post it here

Comment: @ShayanHusaini: The answer already posted solves your problem...

Comment: @ShayanHusaini: What about `((14400 + $hours) * 60 * 60)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = '1400:00:00';

$explode = explode(':',$string);

$hours = $explode[0];

$new_hours = $hours + 20;
```